# Converting a list into a dictionary of the form {name: [other names]} using a function

Tags: python, function, dictionary, list-comprehension

I currently have a lists of captions in the form of a list

```
print(valid_captions)
```

-> `[' Les Lieberman, Barri Lieberman, Isabel Kallman, Trish Iervolino, and  Ron Iervolino ', ' Chuck Grodin ', ' Diana Rosario, Ali Sussman, Sarah Boll, Jen Zaleski, Alysse Brennan, and Lindsay Macbeth ', ' Kelly Murro and Tom Murro ', ' Ron Iervolino, Trish Iervolino, Russ Middleton, and Lisa Middleton ']`

I want to create a function that would iterate over each element of the list and create an adjacency listfor each person where I can get a list of unique names of all the folks that appear in the list within the data set. I want to represent this adjacency list as a python dictionary with each name as the key and the list of names they appear with as the values.

So the function would take a single caption and return a dictionary in the form of
**`name: [other names in caption]}`** for each name while removing any titles like `Dr` or `Mayor`.

As an example I would like this

```
[Dr .Ron Iervolino, Trish Iervolino, and Mayor.Russ Middleton]
```

to return

```
{'Ron Iervolino': ['Trish Iervolino', 'Russ Middleton'],
 'Trish Iervolino': ['Ron Iervolino', 'Russ Middleton'],
 'Russ Middleton': ['Ron Iervolino', 'Russ Middleton']}
```

f someone appears in a caption by themselves, return {name: []}. So the caption 'Robb Stark' would return {'Robb Stark': []}

I have a function to remove the titles, but I'm getting the adjacency list all wrong.

```
def remove_title(names):
    removed_list = []
    for name in names:
        altered_name = re.split('Dr |Mayor ', name)
        removed_list+=altered_name
    try:
        while True:
            removed_list.remove('')
    except:
        pass
    return removed_list
```

Comment: "I have a function to remove the titles, but I'm getting the adjacency list all wrong." Please read [ask] and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and focus your question on the *actual problem you are asking about*. If you had a function that takes cleaned-up name and creates the adjacency list, would you be able to put that together with the other working code in order to solve the problem? If yes, then your **question** is about how to write that function, and you should *only* discuss that function and show its input, expected and actual output.

Comment: If you need more assistance than that, then you probably have more than one question, which should be asked separately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following is my solution to the problem whereby I create  a function that takes a caption and returns a dictionary of the form {name: [other names in caption]} for each name.

In the function, I cleaned up the captions using string manipulation functions  at the very start to remove the titles like 'Mayor', 'Dr' while also stripping out 'and' from the captions. Then I also used  strip() to remove any leading or trailing spaces. I incorporate try and except for any exception handling while removing individual elements of the prospective list and then using for loops for the rest of the process.

```
def format_caption(caption):
    name_list = re.split('Dr |Mayor |and |, ', caption)
    name_list = [name.strip() for name in name_list]
    name_dict = {}
    try:
        while True:
            name_list.remove('')
    except:
        pass
    for name in name_list:
        name_dict.update({name:[]})
    for key, name_list_2 in name_dict.items():
        for name in name_list:
            if name != key:
                name_list_2.append(name)
    return name_dict
```

The resulting function gives me the captions in the format I was looking for

```
list=['Dr .Ron Iervolino, Trish Iervolino, and Mayor.Russ Middleton']
print(format_caption(list))
```

```
>{'Ron Iervolino': ['Trish Iervolino', 'Russ Middleton'],
'Trish Iervolino': ['Ron Iervolino', 'Russ Middleton'],
'Russ Middleton': ['Ron Iervolino', 'Russ Middleton']}
```

Comment: With out an explanation of your code the answer is lacking and can be hard to understand. Please update your answer to include an explanation of **why** it work and **how** it works.

Comment: While it's acceptable and [encouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) to answer your own question, it's best to have a question refined to the point where someone else might actually have it (or close enough to find with a search), and thus an answer that focuses on that question and explains the solution properly. Try to write an *answer* for an audience, even if you wrote the *code* for yourself. That's the main point of the site: to act as a repository of such questions and answers, and thus improve search results.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear to me what format the input list has and what cases other than  `and`,  `,` and `, and` can occur that split the substrings which represent a sublist.

First you need to create a cleaned nested list (list of lists), then you can use this to create the list of dicts of all combinations within each caption:

```
import re


valid_captions = [' Les Lieberman, Barri Lieberman, Isabel Kallman, Trish Iervolino, and  Ron Iervolino ',
                  ' Chuck Grodin ',
                  ' Diana Rosario, Ali Sussman, Sarah Boll, Jen Zaleski, Alysse Brennan, and Lindsay Macbeth ',
                  ' Kelly Murro and Tom Murro ', 
                  ' Ron Iervolino, Trish Iervolino, Russ Middleton, and Lisa Middleton ']

# create cleaned list of lists
cleaned_captions = []
for cap in valid_captions:
    names = re.split(", and|,|and", cap)  # you can add more patterns to split here separated by | -> make sure that if they include each other the longer one comes first
    names = [n.strip() for n in names]
    names = [re.sub("Dr |Mayor ", "", n) for n in names]  # you can add more prefixes to remove here separated by |
    cleaned_captions.append(names)

# create list of dictionaries
other_names_dict_list = [{name: [oth for oth in lst if oth != name] for name in lst} for lst in cleaned_captions]
```

Which will give you:

```
print(cleaned_captions)
> [['Les Lieberman', 'Barri Lieberman', 'Isabel Kallman', 'Trish Iervolino', 'Ron Iervolino'], 
  ['Chuck Grodin'], 
  ['Diana Rosario', 'Ali Sussman', 'Sarah Boll', 'Jen Zaleski', 'Alysse Brennan', 'Lindsay Macbeth'], 
  ['Kelly Murro', 'Tom Murro'], 
  ['Ron Iervolino', 'Trish Iervolino', 'Russ Middleton', 'Lisa Middleton']]

print(other_names_dict_list)
> [{'Les Lieberman': ['Barri Lieberman', 'Isabel Kallman', 'Trish Iervolino', 'Ron Iervolino'], 'Barri Lieberman': ['Les Lieberman', 'Isabel Kallman', 'Trish Iervolino', 'Ron Iervolino'], 'Isabel Kallman': ['Les Lieberman', 'Barri Lieberman', 'Trish Iervolino', 'Ron Iervolino'], 'Trish Iervolino': ['Les Lieberman', 'Barri Lieberman', 'Isabel Kallman', 'Ron Iervolino'], 'Ron Iervolino': ['Les Lieberman', 'Barri Lieberman', 'Isabel Kallman', 'Trish Iervolino']}, 
  {'Chuck Grodin': []}, 
  {'Diana Rosario': ['Ali Sussman', 'Sarah Boll', 'Jen Zaleski', 'Alysse Brennan', 'Lindsay Macbeth'], 'Ali Sussman': ['Diana Rosario', 'Sarah Boll', 'Jen Zaleski', 'Alysse Brennan', 'Lindsay Macbeth'], 'Sarah Boll': ['Diana Rosario', 'Ali Sussman', 'Jen Zaleski', 'Alysse Brennan', 'Lindsay Macbeth'], 'Jen Zaleski': ['Diana Rosario', 'Ali Sussman', 'Sarah Boll', 'Alysse Brennan', 'Lindsay Macbeth'], 'Alysse Brennan': ['Diana Rosario', 'Ali Sussman', 'Sarah Boll', 'Jen Zaleski', 'Lindsay Macbeth'], 'Lindsay Macbeth': ['Diana Rosario', 'Ali Sussman', 'Sarah Boll', 'Jen Zaleski', 'Alysse Brennan']}, 
  {'Kelly Murro': ['Tom Murro'], 'Tom Murro': ['Kelly Murro']}, 
  {'Ron Iervolino': ['Trish Iervolino', 'Russ Middleton', 'Lisa Middleton'], 'Trish Iervolino': ['Ron Iervolino', 'Russ Middleton', 'Lisa Middleton'], 'Russ Middleton': ['Ron Iervolino', 'Trish Iervolino', 'Lisa Middleton'], 'Lisa Middleton': ['Ron Iervolino', 'Trish Iervolino', 'Russ Middleton']}]
```